# How do I replace multiple lines with single word in file(inplace replace)?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed, awk, perl

Content of my `filename` file is as following(for example):

```
My block of line starts from here 
START
First line
second line
third line
END
and end to here for example.
```

I want to replace block of lines between `START` and `END` with just a single word, for example with `SINGLEWORD`. Like below:

```
My block of line starts from here 
SINGLEWORD
and end to here for example.
```

I can find my block of lines with using this command:

```
grep -Pzo "START(.|\n)*END" filename
```

And the result of running above command will be like this:

```
START
First line
second line
third line
END
```

Then I used this command to combine all lines into a single line:

```
LAST_RESULT | sed -e :a -e '/$/N; s/\n/ /; ta'
```

Then I will get this result:

```
START First line second line third line END
```

And with my last command `LAST_RESULTS | sed 's/.*/SINGLEWORD/'` I change them to `"SINGLEWORD"` and I get this result.

```
SINGLEWORD
```

Now what I want is: How can I use this command(Or your suggestion command) and replace(in place)my block of lines to "SINGLEWORD" word? And the final result will be like this file:

```
My block of line starts from here 
SINGLEWORD
and end to here for example.
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This can be done very easily in `perl`:

```
$ perl -i -p0e 's/START.*?END/SINGLEWORD/s' file
$ cat file
My block of line starts from here 
SINGLEWORD
and end to here for example.
```

**Explanation**

`-0` sets the line separator to null

`-p` apply the script given by `-e` to each line and print that line

The regexp modifier:

- `/s` Treat string as single line. That is, change `.` to match any character whatsoever, even a newline, which normally it would not match.

Why the `?`:

- By default, a quantified subpattern is "greedy", that is, it will match as many times as possible (given a particular starting location) while still allowing the rest of the pattern to match. If you want it to match the minimum number of times possible, follow the quantifier with a `?`.

Comment: 6 years later and it's still a great solution, thank you!

Comment: sed had some really crazy syntax to get this working, glad perl handles multiline easier. This seems more like the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 14):

I was wondering if this is possible without `perl`, `python` and others. And I found this solution using `sed`:

```
$ sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/START.*END/SINGLEWORD/g' filename
```

Explanation:

1. **:a** *create a label 'a'*
2. **N** *append the next line to the pattern space*
3. **$!** *if not the last line*, **ba** *branch (go to) label 'a'*
4. **s** *substitute*, `/START.*END/` by `SINGLEWORD`,**/g** *global match (as many times as it can)*

It was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7697604).

Answer (score 2):

While `ripgrep` [specifically doesn't support inline replacement](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/issues/74), I've found that its current `--replace` functionality is already useful for this use case:

```
rg --replace 'SINGLEWORD' --passthru --no-line-number \
--multiline --multiline-dotall 'START.*?END' input.txt > output.txt
```

Explanation:

- `--replace 'SINGLEWORD'` enables replacement mode and sets the replacement string. Can include captured regex groups by using `$1` etc.
- `--passthru` is needed since `ripgrep` usually only shows the lines matching the regex pattern. With this option it also shows all lines from the file that don't match.
- `--no-line-number / -N` is because by default `ripgrep` includes the line numbers in the output (useful when only the matching lines are shown).
- `--multiline / -U` enabled multiline processing since it's disabled by default.
- `--multiline-dotall` is only needed if you want the dot ('.') regex pattern to match newlines (`\n`).
- `> output.txt` is needed since inline replace isn't supported. With the `--passthrough` and `no-line-number` options the standard output matches the desired new file with replacements and can be saved as usual.

However, this command isn't as useful for processing multiple files, as it needs to be run separately per file.